# How to count the elements of a list in a list in a list using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

Imagine the following list:

```
List<List<List<String>>> listRoot = new List<List<List<String>>>();
```

I want to count the elements of the first and the second list and return the accumulated value:

```
    int iFirstListCounter = 0;
    int iSecondListCounter = 0;

    foreach (List<List<String>> listFirst in listRoot)
    {

        iFirstListCounter += listFirst.Count;

        foreach (List<String> listSecond in listFirst)
        {

            iSecondListCounter += listSecond.Count;

        }

    }

    return iFirstListCounter + iSecondListCounter;
```

I just wonder if it's possible to do this using LINQ?

Comment: I think that Rex was thinking about concatenating strings, as the innermost list is a list of strings, and that he reacted to the += operator that scales very badly when used on strings in a loop.

Comment: Yep, that's what happened. Sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int  iTotalListCounter = listRoot.Sum(x => (x.Count + x.Sum(y => y.Count)));
```

Comment: The original poster requested two values. You're only supplying one of them.

Comment: @Eric, I think he only requested the total sum, though you're right in that he does have variables for both. The better question is why was this the accepted answer when it's identical to mine? ;)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. This is a confusingly worded question, and it's not clear to me why the sum is even relevant. It seems like an odd thing to sum.

Comment: @Adam: Because you're not using his weird naming conventions.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: It's because you didn't prefix your variable name with `i`. :)

Comment: iOh iI isee. iWee ishould iof icourse ifollow iany iconvention ithat ithe iOP ihappens ito ifollow... ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
listRoot.SelectMany(l => l.SelectMany(li => li)).Count()
```

Comment: Joel, since neither this answer nor the accepted answer correctly answer the stated problem, which one is "better" seems academic at best. :)

Comment: Also, this technique is asymptotitally slow as the innermost lists become large. If you're in that scenario then you can take advantage of the fact that a list already knows its count.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Technically he didn't mention fastest, but thats true and I agree with Guffas answer then.

Comment: This doesn't return the right value. It only counts the elements in the list containing the strings.

Comment: @timo2oo8: Your question was "How to count the elements of a list in a list in a list using LINQ?". I take it what you were really looking for is iFirstListCounter + iSecondListCounter, which was the selected answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
int totalCount = listRoot.Sum(x => x.Count + x.Sum(y => y.Count));
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
int firstListCounter = listRoot.Sum(f => f.Count);
int secondListCount = listRoot.Sum(f => f.Sum(s => s.Count));
```